# php contact form not returning message

Tags: php, html

Hy guys im trying input a php contact form to my website, but its giving me this error : "Form submission failed and no error message returned from: forms/contact.ph" and i dont know why...

here is my php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $mailTo = "nunomcfernandes12@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;


  mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
  header("Location: index.php=mailsend");
}
```

and here is my html:

```
  <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Insira pelo menos 4 caracteres" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Insira um email valido" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Assunto</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Por favor insira pelo menos 8 caracteres" />
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" data-rule="required" data-msg="Por favor escreva-nos algo!"></textarea>
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <div class="loading">A carregar...</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">A sua mensagem foi enviada, obrigado!</div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar mensagem</button></div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: Where do you receive that error? Please post code that shows the error message you are receiving.

Comment: Hey , how are you? The error that gives me is on the website not on the code.  And this is the error “ Form submission failed and no error message returned from: forms/contact.ph”

Comment: What does the developer console show?

Comment: It doesn’t show nothing

Comment: That is not possible. It would at least show a 200 successful page load. View network tab, reload, and resubmit form

Comment: Hey I tried and now it’s giving me the error 500

Comment: So you have a fatal server error. Look at the servers error log.

Comment: Hmm Okok I will see

Answer (score -1):

Change your `$headers` to this:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $mailFrom"."\r\n";
```

Also, check your SPAM/JUNK

This method send as spam almost

Comment: Hey dude, I don't know if you read the whole question,  but I am getting an error on submitting the form, therefore I cannot send or receive any emails from it, because my php mail() function is not being triggered nor activated.

 Do you have any ideas for the error? What it means and if there is a way to do error handling in this case?

Comment: Add this code first line to show error: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: I added that to my code, and now? where does the error show?

Comment: submit again form. in contact.php should be show error. if not show error, add `phpinfo();` to your file and check `mail()` is active?

Comment: @Nunofernandes.official you testing on localhost or server?

Comment: localhost im using xampp

Comment: @Nunofernandes.official mail() function not work on localhost. test on real server.

Comment: But how can I test on a real server without pay xd , I don’t want to put this website on-line I just want to learn how to make the basic of a website

Comment: Use free host. search "free web host" in google.

Comment: Hey bro! I tried that free web host , and now I think it’s kinda working , because it gives me the error 500 xd